# mongodb to postgres 2 way streaming replication

Tags: mysql, mongodb, postgresql, database-replication

Hi This question might be too broad for stack overflow community. If anyone can give me suggestions about it that would be very helpful.

I am currently using mongodb as my active backend for all the operations part. I am planning to use postgresql or mysql (whichever feasible in my case) for the reporting and analytics purpose as well as syncing it locally with my Desktop application to display data on client side.

I tried [MOSQL](https://github.com/stripe/mosql) but it seems like MOSQL doesn't support mongodb v3.0.
I figured out how to pass data between mongodb and postgres via a python script. But could figure out how to pass selective data when new data comes.

Can anybody help me with some tool or script which can help me setup a replication of mongodb in Postgres or Mysql?

Comment: Yes way to broad. You can read information about wrties from the oplog for mongodb as this is how mongod to mongod replication is done anyway. For any SQL database, the general way to iterface with other systems is use triggers or otherwise tap into comit changes to record and act on the changes. In all cases you need to monitor the oplog with a custom program, and similarly send data from triggers into some generic change table and follow that. Way too involved for an answer here.

Comment: Can you give us an idea about the python script you used to do the streaming replication? I'm running into trouble with MOSQL

Comment: You can use two methods. Either you can dump the data into a csv file and use that file to import data to postgres. Or you can directly import data from mongo to postgres using sql queries. First complete your script and then you can use a cron job to set up periodic updates. Also you can use checks/triggers at postgres end to check if a row/data is already present and skip it.